# Disabling today widget on IOS10 devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, today-extension, ios10-today-widget

I have an existing app and i want to release a version to support IOS10 devices.
The problem is that my app today widget not is supporting the new today view in IOS10 and i want to disable the today widget to all IOS10 users.
It it possible? I already tried to set to today widget to Base SDK of 9.3 from XCode build settings and it didn't work
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **show/hide the widget** from within you **Containing** **App** based on your requirement.

```
    if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            NCWidgetController.widgetController().setHasContent(false, forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier: "YourWidgetBundleIdentifier")
        })
    }
```

Comment: I am getting an error for 'Use of unresolved identifier 'NCWidgetController' in Containing App. Please help.

Comment: Which `iOS version` are you using?

Comment: Add `import NotificationCenter` to the top of your file.

Comment: this does work however the widget is still available and can still be added to the Today View. It just does not show anything.